# Bootstrap 4 (alpha 6) brand get's centered and overlaps with toggler

Tags: bootstrap-4, overlap

When using navbar and container in Bootrap 4 (alpha 6) like

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">

<div class="container">

    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-toggler-div" aria-controls="navbar-toggler-div" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Navigation">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </button>

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
        Band name here
    </a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-toggler-div">

        <ul class="navbar-nav">

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Foo</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Bar</a>
            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>

</div>
```

and when the screen is very small (like on cell phones) the brand logo / text (does not matter) and the toggler 
* get centered 
* do overlap (toggler is not next to the brand but "on" it)

This applies to other navbar types (fixed-top, default), too.

When removing "container" after the nav element, everything is fine.

I need the container div for having a full width navbar but which is "centered" itself (like the following content).

Comment: Can you create a working fiddle of your problem? I have created a bs4a6 nav template here: https://jsfiddle.net/80ktkq37/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/p47Lqb9f/

Comment: Did the answer work for you? If so, don't forget the click the accept button.

Comment: No, you removed the container, which I need. See my original post. Maybe I can re-format my question to "I need a BS4 'template' where the nav (a) is 100% width [background etc.] but (b) it's _content_ has the same width als the page 'body', NOT full screen width"

Answer (score 3):

I could "solve" it by adding the following css for the container

```
@media (max-width: 576px) {
    nav .container {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

@Escher: The .container after nav is also in BS 4's official css, as well as in their documentation. So I believe it's intended.

Comment: For future readers, you can accept your own answer if it solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have an additional `<div class="container">` flexbox container in your `<nav>` menu that shouldn't be there, and so bootstrap tries to automatically align all the items to the center. Remove that `div` and it works.

Here's your fiddle updated with the `<div class="container">` removed:
https://jsfiddle.net/p47Lqb9f/1/

Comment: Exactly this container is needed, see my original post: "I need the container div for having a full width navbar but which is "centered" itself (like the following content)."